# Will Haise regain his memories and adopt to his true personality as Kaneki again?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

Will Haise become Kaneki again? By that, I mean if Haise will regain his memories and adopt his true personality as Kaneki?

I have a little bit knowledge of Haise's backstory (how Kaneki became amnesiac) but I haven't watched season 3 or read the manga (both *Tokyo Ghoul* and *Tokyo Ghoul:re*) yet.

Did this event occur in the anime or in the manga yet?

Answer (score 1):

If I skimmed the manga and read the wiki properly, *and* if the writers and such follow it,

> I believe he will return soon, because he will continue to develop and adopt the title of One-Eyed King. After a bout with Arima and Eto. Then starts his own group called "Goat."